# integrating POLi payment with PHP

Tags: php, xml, e-commerce

I need help in integrating POLi payment with custom PHP(no cms)
here is a link to a **official** [pdf file](http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CB4QxQEwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fviewer%3Fa%3Dv%26q%3Dcache%3ABqZ3UNNnZTUJ%3Apolipayments.com%2FAssets%2FDocs%2FPOLiWebServicesMIG.pdf%2Bpoli%2Bpayment%2Bapi%26hl%3Den%26gl%3Dpk%26pid%3Dbl%26srcid%3DADGEESh8NXqqQ0tAp7ElO_IHTO66EZEGbKM4342SmVXkUv8zQqch27QyVZCNam0gndPLx_rzV9Yhx2FkNQ-mtslMCUVrXsY-ocPMjV9TyTw6le7_eqhGADk3Kp2V2BaxD6m4aoaV_kve%26sig%3DAHIEtbSU43EsH-aQEHdY4TV_VmsDUqncbw&rct=j&q=poli%20payment%20api&ei=2dxxTo_oCsvwrQfS-qHlDQ&usg=AFQjCNFqwLKqN2CVD-JPyxzjYtx0h5Gv_g&cad=rja)
May be i need this section of code to integrate with php (from this [pdf file](http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CB4QxQEwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fviewer%3Fa%3Dv%26q%3Dcache%3ABqZ3UNNnZTUJ%3Apolipayments.com%2FAssets%2FDocs%2FPOLiWebServicesMIG.pdf%2Bpoli%2Bpayment%2Bapi%26hl%3Den%26gl%3Dpk%26pid%3Dbl%26srcid%3DADGEESh8NXqqQ0tAp7ElO_IHTO66EZEGbKM4342SmVXkUv8zQqch27QyVZCNam0gndPLx_rzV9Yhx2FkNQ-mtslMCUVrXsY-ocPMjV9TyTw6le7_eqhGADk3Kp2V2BaxD6m4aoaV_kve%26sig%3DAHIEtbSU43EsH-aQEHdY4TV_VmsDUqncbw&rct=j&q=poli%20payment%20api&ei=2dxxTo_oCsvwrQfS-qHlDQ&usg=AFQjCNFqwLKqN2CVD-JPyxzjYtx0h5Gv_g&cad=rja))

->GenerateURL  Request
To  generate  a  Payment  URL,  the  merchant  performs  a  HTTP(S)  post  to  the  POLi™
PaymentAPI  REST  URL  with  the  request  content-­‐type  set  to  ‘text/xml’  and  the  following
XML  data  in  the  request  body.

> Manual  request  (RequestType    =  ‘Manual’)

```
<?xml  version="1.0"  encoding="utf-­‐8"?>  
<PaymentDataRequest  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-­‐instance">  

<MerchantCode>PriceBusterDVD</MerchantCode>  

<AuthenticationCode>MerchantPassword</AuthenticationCode>  

<RequestType>Manual</RequestType>  

<PaymentAmount>123.11</PaymentAmount>  

<PaymentReference>LandingPageReferenceText</PaymentReference>  

<ConfirmationEmail>No</ConfirmationEmail>  

<CustomerReference>No</CustomerReference>  

<RecipientName></RecipientName>  

<RecipientEmail></RecipientEmail>  
</PaymentDataRequest>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this without any framework will require the use of CURL and sending the XML with the post fields.

```
$payload = '<?xml  version="1.0"  encoding="utf-­‐8"?>  
           <PaymentDataRequest  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-­‐instance">  
           <MerchantCode>PriceBusterDVD</MerchantCode>  
           <AuthenticationCode>MerchantPassword</AuthenticationCode>  
           <RequestType>Manual</RequestType>  
           <PaymentAmount>123.11</PaymentAmount>  
           <PaymentReference>LandingPageReferenceText</PaymentReference>  
           <ConfirmationEmail>No</ConfirmationEmail>  
           <CustomerReference>No</CustomerReference>  
           <RecipientName></RecipientName>  
           <RecipientEmail></RecipientEmail>  
           </PaymentDataRequest>';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://polipaymenturl.com'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
```

See the [PHP cURL book](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for more information about using cURL.

(Note the example I have given isn't tested and is missing the correct URL but this should set you on the right path)